# Python:How to get the same row a number of times

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to get same raw multiple times like bellow.

```
A=[2,3,4,5]
B=[[2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5],...,[2,3,4,5]]
```

Number of rows can be change.
How can I do this problem?

Comment: Did you try anything? What happened?

Comment: I found answer myself thanks drop me down.

Comment: It can be get like this B=[A]*n

Comment: @kgdc you can try it, but you may be surprised by the results. Lists are *mutable*, if you need to edit one without the others changing they need to be separate objects.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
B = [[i for i in A] for n in range(5)]
```

Change the value in the `range ()` call to change the number of copies. This doesn't suffer from reference sharing like the other answers.

<kbd>[online example](http://ideone.com/VF8aw5)</kbd>

Or a shorter equivalent:

```
B = [A[:] for n in range(5)]
```

This also doesn't suffer from reference sharing because the slice operator creates a deep copy* as well.

<kbd>[online example](http://ideone.com/27GwnJ)</kbd>

* at least in terms of this input

Comment: when I used trying this method,there are two for loop then couldn't the code be slowed down? and "[A]*n"  is this method also same to your run time complexity?

Comment: @kgdc `[A]*n` results in `n` 'copies' of the same list. Each copy actually being a reference, and so not independent.  This code produces a deep copy (copying all the elements)

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, just doing list comprehension in the simplest way will only make multiple references to the same old list. To instead ensure we get a new copy of the list, we can do:

```
A = [2, 3, 4, 5]
B = [list(A) for i in range(10)]
```

where `list(A)` ensures that we get a copy of `A` instead of a reference to the same list.

Comment: what are the deferences of comparing with above answer. "B = [[i for i in A] for n in range(10)]"

Comment: Well, the syntax for one thing. I think it looks a little bit more readable to keep it at only one layer of list comprehension. Then I would guess - but I am not sure - that my suggestion should be a bit quicker, as it allows for the whole list to be copied in one go, instead of built element by element (with the overhead that can incur when looking at close-to-metal memory allocation et c.).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
B=([A.copy()]*10)
```

However, it can produce references between the lists in B if their elements are complex object. But if you're using it for ints, strings and others basic stuffs it's going to work well.

Answer (score -2):

```
A = [1,2,3]
B= []
n= 5
for i in range(5):
    B.append(A)
```

where A is list, B is resultant list and n is number of rows